# How to set maximum file size for check-ins in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Is there a server-side setting for TFS to set the maximum file size that can be checked-in to TFS? I am talking about all files and not work item attachments.

Comment: AFAIK there is no limit. Are you encountering a specific difficulty? Also, what version of TFS?

Comment: I have no problem per se. I just want to limit server side so users cannot upload large files such as installation ISO files to the server. It would be lovely to set the maximum limit to say 1 Gb.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking Git, then navigate to /_admin/_versioncontrol, choose the repo in question, switch to the Options tab in the central pane and set the setting in the dropdown to the appropriate value:

[image]

I failed to find a similar setting for TFVC repo. Not sure if it means some hardcoded file size or no limitation.

Comment: Thx for the tip. I was actually thinking about TFVC repos. Lets hope someone knows.